# Determine if object is integer

Tags: java, object, integer

How to determine if Object is Integer? Something like:

```
if (obj.isInteger()) {...}
```

Comment: other way : `if ((Object)(obj).getClass()==Integer.class) {}`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
if (obj instanceof Integer) {....}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
if(ob instanceof Integer)

{ your code/logic here}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use [Class.isInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) method - This method is the `dynamic` equivalent of the Java *language* `instanceof` operator.

Comment: The link is broken. References to newer doc will be in future too I think